# Yup Validation causing errors

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm trying to validate my forms on React using yup and useForm, I've followed every step of the tutorial but I am still receiving errors. I am receiving 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined'. This is odd because I have already named it in the input value. How can I fix this?

P.s I have tried using {...register} and ref={register} don't seem to matter.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required("First Name should be required please"),
  lastName: yup.string().required(),
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
});
const Submission = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const submitForm = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <div className="Form">
      <div className="title">Sign Up</div>
      <div className="inputs">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            {...register('firstName')} 
            placeholder="First Name..."
          />
          <p> {errors.firstName?.message} </p>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="Last Name..."
            ref={register}
          />
          <p> {errors.lastName?.message} </p>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email..."
            ref={register}
          />
          <p> {errors.email?.message} </p>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" />
 </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Submission;
```

The exact error I am recieving looks like this:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm still using the outdated version of the library.
From this,

```
<input type="text"name="email"placeholder="Email..."ref={register}/>

const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
```

To this

```
{...register("email", { required: "Email is Required"})};

const { register,handleSubmit, formState: { errors },} = useForm();
```